# Windows Azure copying dependent assemblies

Tags: assemblies, azure-worker-roles

I'm trying to deploy a Windows Azure Worker Role to the cloud. The VS2010 contains three projects like so:

1. Cloud project
2. Worker role project
3. Helper class project

My Helper class project uses a reference to a WIF assembly(Microsoft.IdentityModel). The Worker role project references the Helper class. I have set the *Copy Local* to *true* for both the Helper and the WIF assembly. When I package and deploy to my cloud service, I have a warning which says:

*The project 'WorkerService' is dependent on the following assembly: C:\Users\foo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelloCloud\Helper\bin\Debug\Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll. This assembly is not in the package. To make sure that the role starts, add this assembly as a reference to the project and set the Copy Local property to true.*

My worker role keeps crashing every time it tries to run. Upon seeing the Intellitrace log, I see that all the assemblies except the Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll are copied over.

How can I get the required assembly in the Helper class to copy over to the service package?

Thanks,
Mike.

Answer (score 0):

mmm..."Copy Local" has worked for me (I just deployed a simple app on a Web Role and it worked). Not sure why the worker role doesn't.

I did find this article though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh403974.aspx

You might want to try that out. (I haven't)

Comment: The asker states that he has Copy Local set to true. The article you linked to is no longer there. So this answer is N/A.